# AVAudioRecorder not Working in iOS8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, xcode6

I have implemented AVAudiorecorder for recording and playing voice for 10 secs.it is working fine with iOS 7.But when i run the same code on ios8 ,it is not working please help.
Here is a source Code.

```
    //Below is my code for recording and Playing.

 //Here is the Recording code which records sound for 10 secs

 AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
 NSError *err = nil;
 [audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
 if(err){
    return;
 }
 [audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
 err = nil;

  // Setup audio recording
 recordSetting = @{AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                                 AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: @(AVAudioQualityLow),
                                 AVNumberOfChannelsKey: @1,
                                 AVSampleRateKey: @22050.0f};

 recorderFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MySound.wave", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER];
 NSData *postData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:recorderFilePath];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath];err = nil;
 NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[url path] options: 0 error:&err];

 if(audioData)
 {NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fm removeItemAtPath:[url path] error:&err];}
 err = nil;
 recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:&err];

 //prepare to record
 [recorder setDelegate:self];
 [recorder prepareToRecord];
 recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;


//Please help me out and tell if i have to add/modify something because it is working in ios7.
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a widget?  Why did you tag your post with the widget tag?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there isn't nothing wrong in your code snippet.
I use approximately the same code to make a registration on my iPhone, too.
The only difference with my code is a call to

```
[recorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval) 10];
```

in order to start the registration for 10 seconds